# Haskell type not clear

Tags: haskell, higher-order-functions

One of the exercises I am trying has defined a function as follows:

```
twice f x = f (f x)
```

When I print the type of twice I see:

```
Main> :t twice
twice :: (a -> a) -> a -> a
```

Not sure I understand the output here. So `twice` takes an input of type function (which is of type `a -> a`). Is this correct? If so then how was the `f` evaluated to be of type function (`a -> a`)? And then what is the return type of `twice` here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
twice    f            x  =   f (f x)
twice :: (a -> a) ->  a  ->  a
```

it is like this.

`f` is of type `a -> a`, x is of type `a`, `f (f x)` is of type `a`.

You should pass `f` as `a -> a` function, such as `* 2`

Comment: Ah I see it now. So how was the type of 'f' evaluated to be of type a->a. How did the interpreter deduce it's type? I have not defined 'f' anywhere.

Comment: Someone seem to have asked a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42243902/haskell-function-type-clarification?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's correct.

`f` has a type of `a -> a`

It takes `x` which has a type of `a` and should be able to use his output again, so the output should be the same type as the input.

And `twice` has the same output type as a call from `f`, so `a`.

Which gives us this:

```
twice :: (a -> a) -> a -> a
twice     f          x =  f (f x)
```